# How to preload images using grails resource tags.

Tags: grails

I'm using resource tags for grails resource plugin to set the src of an image.

`src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'bla.png')}`" 
This works great and takes care of whether to use http or https behind the scenes for me. The problem is I want to be able to preload these images.

I used to do something like this is JS.

```
$(['images/bla.png','images/bla2.png']).each(function(){
  $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
});
```

The problem with the above is it's not using any resource tag it defaults to loading them as http and not https. 
Anyone know a way around this. Or how I might preload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a variable in your GSP to store the images that need to be preloaded and have your javascript read that variable. For example:

**GSP**

```
var preload_images = [];
preload_images.push("${resource(dir:'images',file:'bla.png')}");
preload_images.push("${resource(dir:'images',file:'foo.png')}");
```

**Javascript**

```
$(preload_images).each(function(){
  $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
});
```